# Facebook integration Adobe AIR iOS and Android

Tags: ios, facebook, air, packager-for-iphone

I was wondering if anyone has had experience using AS3 Facebook integration on mobile devices with Adobe AIR for iOS packager or Android? Ive used the Facebook API for AS3 before for websites but not sure it its feasible using it inside an iOS packager application?
All my client is wanting to do is post a highscore to a users wall.